# Parameter not retuning in ActivatedRoute

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I'm unable to get the parameter from the route, it needs to then call a function within the component which then calls to the service.

I've added it to the constructor as I believed it may not be passing through in time if it's in NgInit but still no luck.

I've added a console.log and it's just printing null and I can see it's calling the function but not passing the parameter.

I'm sure it's super basic and I've just made an error somewhere.

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent},
  { path: 'tap/:tapcode', component: AppComponent}
];
```

app.component.ts

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private dataService: DataService) {

    this.tapCode = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('tapcode');
    console.log(this.tapCode);
    this.getScreen(this.tapCode);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it inside `ngOnInit()` life cycle method?

Comment: @AmitChigadani yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the data was not available in ActivatedRoute, only in ActivationEnd as it was manually typed into the address bar.

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private dataService: DataService) {

      this.router.events.pipe( filter(event=> event instanceof ActivationEnd && event.snapshot.children.length == 0))
      .subscribe((event: ActivationEnd) => {
        console.log(event.snapshot.params);
      });
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot when resolving manually typed parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try get activeted route snapshot inside **ngOnInit** like this;

```
ngOnInit(){

this.tapCode = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('tapcode');

    }
```

or you can subscribe route like this;

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.tapCode = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('tapcode');
  })
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-far56b

Comment: No deal, still returning null under subscription. I already tried placing this under ngInit instead of Constructor and same result.

Comment: Hey @hylian, can you share your code via stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Now only change in app.component.ts

```
 constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router,
private dataService: DataService) {

this.route.paramMap.subscribe((param=>{ this.tapCode=param.get('tapcode')
}));     
console.log(this.tapCode);
this.getScreen(this.tapCode);}
```

Comment: you are already on parent component ,you have to declare that same component as a child if you want to pass data to same component

Comment: No deal :( - just returns undefined.

Comment: No - just returns null. I believe it's to do with github.com/angular/angular/issues/19420

Answer (score 0):

You can get route params directly inside params.tapCode.

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private dataService: DataService) {

   // this.tapCode = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('tapcode');

    this.tapCode = this.route.snapshot.params.tapcode; //try this
    console.log(this.tapCode);
    this.getScreen(this.tapCode);
  }
```

Reference: 
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Comment: I have tracing enabled and can see it being recognised as tapcode: value but I can't get it out of the object - still showing as undefined.

Comment: Maybe have you tried this.route.snapshot.params['tapcode']. Or can you show a screenshot of tracing?

Comment: yes have tried this. I actually think it may be because of: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19420, trace output attached here: https://imgur.com/a/nvTWCDl